# Making a simple text rpg and there's an attribute error?

Tags: python, attributeerror

So I've been doing LPTHW, and you know that 'make a text-based RPG' we're supposed to do? Well, I've certainly been doing it, but every time I try to run it, this error pops up:

```
File "DimensionSpace.py", line 826, in <module>
    a_game.play()
  File "DimensionSpace.py", line 22, in play
    next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'enter'
```

I'm actually fairly confused. That part is the part I stuck with the book for. Here's what the code looks like:

```
    from sys import exit
from random import randint
from textwrap import dedent

class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
       print("This scene is not yet configured.")
       print("Subclass it and implement enter().")
       exit(1)

class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('credits')

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What is `scene_map`?

Comment: scene_map goes to a class called Map.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the brackets in your play function:

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
```

Because you are not calling the function and thus are not getting a scene object back, you assign the function itself to `current_scene`. Calling the enter function on the function object does not make sense.